# How can I get to the parent scope of my inline javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, inline, anonymous

I have something similar to this

```
function testfunction(runthis)
{
    runthis();
}

function main()
{
     var z = 15;
     testfunction(function(){ alert(z); });
}
```

However it doesn't think z is in the same scope as my inline function. Without adding additional parameters to testfunction or my inline function, is there any way for my inline function to belong to the same scope as main? I'm trying to make callback functions work.

**Edit:** the above I imagine is a crappy example because it seems to be working. However the instance here http://pastebin.com/A1pq8dJR does not work unless I add .call(this,parameters) and manually set the scope (although I'm not exactly sure what this is doing). I would have thought this used there would refer to the scope imageLoaded has, but it is referring to the scope of imageBoxCreate? Could anyone explain why it wont work without that and why doing this fixed it?

Comment: Can you please describe your intent better? The above works and alerts `15` thanks to closures. I don't understand what you mean by "belong to same scope".

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You'll get an alert of `15` with the posted code...

Comment: It's not working for me unless I put .call(this,parameters) after my function call. http://pastebin.com/A1pq8dJR that's a link to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just invoke a global function in javascript, the `this` object will be the top level `window` global object.  If you invoke a function using the dot operator on an object, then `this` will be that object when the function runs.  When you use `function.call`, you are explicitly specifying which object should be `this`.  I think you are likely just making some scope mistakes with how you use `this` and `var`, but your code is long enough and involved enough that I'm not going to spend the time to debug it for you.  If you can isolate you issue with a smaller code sample, folks should be able to help more easily.